# jQuery is not executing in my Groovy Server Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

I have a jQuery function that isn't executing in my Groovy Server Page. I have my controller's function simply render an error message but it shows up on the "next" web page instead of showing up on the "same" web page as in Ajax. I did verify that jQuery does load on my controller's GSP view using the "View Source" feature of the Chrome browser.

Here is my controller's function regarding the error message that I wish to display:

```
def displayerror = {
    render "Login or Password incorrect!"
}
```

and here is what I have in the head element of my GSP:

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" />
<r:layoutResources/>
```

I learned that the layoutResources line is necessary or my GSP doesn't even pick up jQuery.

Finally, here is what I have in the body of my GSP which pertains to this problem:

```
<g:link action = "displayerror" elementId = "errorMessage">Error!</g:link>
    <div id = "time">
    </div>
    <r:script>
        $("#errorMessage").click(function() {
            (#"time").load(this.href);
            return false;
        });
    </r:script>
```

This is just a link I created to test if I can get Ajax to work before I use it for what I really need.

Any help tremendously appreciated. Oh, and before I forget, I have this line in my BuildConfig.groovy:

```
runtime ":jquery:1.11.0.2"
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to verify that jquery is actually being included in the rendered HTML (i.e.- a script tag)?

Comment: I verified by doing the "Inspect Element" from the right click menu in the Chrome browser, then going to the "Resources" menu. There, I expanded the "Frames" menu and it had a "Scripts" menu under it. When I expand "Scripts", I see "jquery-1.11.0.min.js" listed under it. I did this on the web page that has the "Error!" link on it which is supposed to do everything that I want done in the jQuery function.

Comment: Ok, I believe the problem is related to what Rituraj and I cover in our answers. His is simply a long-form way with unnecessary boilerplate code IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach, maybe a simple approach, is to use the grails gsp  tag. Using this, you can get rid of the javascript function and so you will remove everything between your  tags or comment it out just to see how things work and do something like:

```
 <g:remoteLink controller = "controller" action = "displayerror" update = "time">Error!</g:remoteLink>
    <div id = "time">
    </div>
<%-- Below this line is your old code that is commented out -->
<%--        <r:script>--%>
<%--            $(function () {--%>
<%--                $("#errorMessage").click(function(e) {--%>
<%--                    e.preventDefault();--%>
<%--                    $("#time").load(this.href);--%>
<%--                    });--%>
<%--            });--%>
<%--        </r:script>--%>
```

Replace "controller" in the above code with whatever your concerned controller's name is.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, when working with jQuery, it is a good idea to use the ready event. This will ensure that any event handlers you add to your elements will be added only after said elements have been rendered. This is what Rituraj attempts to cover in his answer, but here is the "jQuery way" to do it:

```
$(function () {
    $("#errorMessage").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#time").load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Also, the `false` return is unnecessary here, as you have already prevented the default anchor action.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering about the false return being needed. So, I tried your suggestion changing nothing else but taking out the false return line and I got the same result. My error message is printed but not asynchronously. It is printed on a separate "next" web page refresh. Hmmm, what could it be? Same result on Rituraj's solution. I feel its something small and silly that I just can't see.

Comment: Can you verify that the anchor tag is, in fact, being rendered with an id of 'errorMessage'?

Comment: Next thing would be to utilize Chrome dev tools to debug, setting a breakpoint at `e.preventDefault();`, to verify that the click handler is in fact being called when you click the link.

Answer (score 0):

first add jQuery file then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#errorMessage").click(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
                $("#time").load(this.href);
                return false;
            });
  });
```

Comment: Rituraj, what do you mean by "first add jQuery file"? Have I not done that already? Thanks for clarification.